# ある箇所をクリックするとショートカットキーが反応しなくなる

Tags: qt

Ctrl+Fのショートカットキーで指定した場所に移動する機能を実装したのですが、表示内容を変更する機能のコンボボックスを押した後、このショートカットキーが反応しなくなる不具合が発生しています。本来はコンボボックスを押した後でもショートカットキーが反応するのが正常な動作です。

試したこととしては、ボタンのソースコードに下記のショートカットキーのソースコードを追加してみたのですが、改善しませんでした。この場合、コンボボックスのソースコードにショートカットキーの処理を追記すればよろしいでしょうか。ご助言の程お願いします。

```c
// Ctrl+Fで検索ウィンドウを開く
    property bool is_key_control: false
    property bool is_key_f: false
    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: (event)=> {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Control) {
                is_key_control = true
                event.accepted = true;
            }
            else if (event.key === Qt.Key_F) {
                is_key_f = true
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
        Keys.onReleased: (event)=> {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Control) {
                is_key_control = false
                event.accepted = true;
            }
            else if (event.key === Qt.Key_F) {
                is_key_f = false
                event.accepted = true;
            }
            else {
                // 何もしない
                return;
            }

            if (((is_key_control == true) && (is_key_f == false)) ||
                ((is_key_control == false) && (is_key_f == true))) {
                if (symbol_search_window.visible === false){
                    symbol_search_window.visible = true
                    symbol_search_window.x=symbol_search_button.x + 50 //座標リセット
                    symbol_search_window.y=symbol_search_button.y + 100

                    is_key_control = false
                    is_key_f = false

                    //コンボボックスの更新
                    dispManager.ReadSymbolSearchFile()
                    dispManager.UpdateSymbolKind()
                    dispManager.UpdateSymbolName(symbol_kind_combo.textAt(0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ボタンのソースコードは下記の通りです。

```
ComboBox{
        id:viewmode
        x:80
        y:5
        height:35
        width:125
        currentIndex:0

        //表示モード選択ボックス(コンボボックス)の見た目変更
        background: Rectangle{
            color:Color.combobox
            border.color: Color.combobox_border
        }
        //リストの見た目
        delegate: ItemDelegate{
            id:combobox_style
            width:viewmode.width - 2
            height:20
            padding:0
            contentItem:Text{
                color:hovered? Color.combobox_list_text_hover : Color.combobox_list_text　//マウスカーソルを合わせたときに色を変える
                text:modelData
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                leftPadding: 20
            }
            background: Rectangle{
                color:hovered? Color.combobox_list_hover : Color.combobox_list　//マウスカーソルを合わせたときに色を変える
                anchors.left:combobox_style.left
                anchors.leftMargin:  1
                width:combobox_style.width
                height:combobox_style.height
            }
        }

        //combobox右端の逆三角形を描画
        indicator:Canvas{
            id:canvas
            x:viewmode.width - width - viewmode.rightPadding
            y:viewmode.topPadding + (viewmode.availableHeight - height) / 2
            width: 12
            height: 8
            contextType: "2d"

            Connections{
                target:viewmode
                function onPressedChanged(){canvas.requestPaint();}
            }
            onPaint:{
                context.reset();
                context.moveTo(0,0);
                context.lineTo(width, 0);
                context.lineTo(width / 2, height);
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle = viewmode.pressed ? Color.combobox_canvas_pressed:Color.combobox_canvas;
                context.fill();
            }
        }

        //comboboxのテキストを調整
        contentItem: Text{
            leftPadding: 5
            text:viewmode.displayText
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            elide:Text.ElideRight
        }

        model:ListModel{
            property bool completed: false
            Component.onCompleted: {
                append({text:Text_Js.viewmode_list1[Text_Js.language_no]})
                append({text:Text_Js.viewmode_list2[Text_Js.language_no]})
                append({text:Text_Js.viewmode_list3[Text_Js.language_no]})
                append({text:Text_Js.viewmode_list4[Text_Js.language_no]})
                append({text:Text_Js.viewmode_list5[Text_Js.language_no]})
                append({text:Text_Js.viewmode_list6[Text_Js.language_no]})
            }
        }
        onActivated: {
            if(viewmode.currentIndex === 0){ //Line OverView
                window.segment_visible = true
                window.segment_add001_visible = true
                window.segment_add002_visible = false
                window.tc_visible = false
                window.tc_add002_visible = false
                window.tc_add003_visible = false
                window.signal_visible = false
                window.signal_add001_visible = false
                window.sw_visible = false
                window.sw_add002_visible = false
                window.trainStop_visible = false
                window.trainStop_add001_visible = false
                window.virtualSignal_visible = false
                window.virtualSignal_add001_visible = false
                window.virtualBlock_visible = false
                window.virtualBlock_add001_visible = false
                window.awsTS_visible = false
                window.awsTS_add001_visible = false
                window.cbtcTS_visible = false
                window.cbtcTS_add001_visible = false
                window.rlTS_visible = false
                window.rlTS_add001_visible = false
                window.transponder_visible = false
                window.transponder_add001_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_add001_visible = false
                window.bumper_visible = false
                window.bumper_add001_visible = false
                window.dangerousPoint_visible = false
                window.sieve_visible = false
                window.sieve_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_visible = true
                window.platform_add001_visible = true
                window.platform_add002_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add002_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_add001_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_add002_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.update_view = false //表示変化なし
                window.train_view = false //列車表示なし
                window.symbol_visible = false
            }else if(viewmode.currentIndex === 1){ //Line Detail1
                window.segment_visible = true
                window.segment_add001_visible = true
                window.segment_add002_visible = false
                window.tc_visible = true
                window.tc_add002_visible = false
                window.tc_add003_visible = false
                window.signal_visible = true
                window.signal_add001_visible = false
                window.sw_visible = true
                window.sw_add002_visible = false
                window.trainStop_visible = true
                window.trainStop_add001_visible = false
                window.virtualSignal_visible = true
                window.virtualSignal_add001_visible = false
                window.virtualBlock_visible = true
                window.virtualBlock_add001_visible = false
                window.awsTS_visible = true
                window.awsTS_add001_visible = false
                window.cbtcTS_visible = true
                window.cbtcTS_add001_visible = false
                window.rlTS_visible = true
                window.rlTS_add001_visible = false
                window.transponder_visible = false
                window.transponder_add001_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_add001_visible = false
                window.bumper_visible = false
                window.bumper_add001_visible = false
                window.dangerousPoint_visible = false
                window.sieve_visible = false
                window.sieve_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_visible = false
                window.platform_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_add002_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add002_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_add001_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_add002_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.update_view = true //表示変化あり
                window.train_view = true //列車表示あり
                window.symbol_visible = false
            }else if(viewmode.currentIndex === 2){ //Line Detail2
                window.segment_visible = true
                window.segment_add001_visible = true
                window.segment_add002_visible = true
                window.tc_visible = true
                window.tc_add002_visible = true
                window.tc_add003_visible = true
                window.signal_visible = true
                window.signal_add001_visible = true
                window.sw_visible = true
                window.sw_add002_visible = true
                window.trainStop_visible = true
                window.trainStop_add001_visible = true
                window.virtualSignal_visible = true
                window.virtualSignal_add001_visible = true
                window.virtualBlock_visible = true
                window.virtualBlock_add001_visible = true
                window.awsTS_visible = true
                window.awsTS_add001_visible = true
                window.cbtcTS_visible = true
                window.cbtcTS_add001_visible = true
                window.rlTS_visible = true
                window.rlTS_add001_visible = true
                window.transponder_visible = false
                window.transponder_add001_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_add001_visible = false
                window.bumper_visible = false
                window.bumper_add001_visible = false
                window.dangerousPoint_visible = false
                window.sieve_visible = false
                window.sieve_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_visible = false
                window.platform_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_add002_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add002_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_add001_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_add002_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.update_view = true //表示変化あり
                window.train_view = false //列車表示なし
                window.symbol_visible = true
            }else if(viewmode.currentIndex === 3){ //Line Detail3
                window.segment_visible = true
                window.segment_add001_visible = true
                window.segment_add002_visible = false
                window.tc_visible = true
                window.tc_add002_visible = false
                window.tc_add003_visible = false
                window.signal_visible = true
                window.signal_add001_visible = false
                window.sw_visible = true
                window.sw_add002_visible = false
                window.trainStop_visible = true
                window.trainStop_add001_visible = false
                window.virtualSignal_visible = true
                window.virtualSignal_add001_visible = false
                window.virtualBlock_visible = true
                window.virtualBlock_add001_visible = false
                window.awsTS_visible = true
                window.awsTS_add001_visible = false
                window.cbtcTS_visible = true
                window.cbtcTS_add001_visible = false
                window.rlTS_visible = true
                window.rlTS_add001_visible = false
                window.transponder_visible = true
                window.transponder_add001_visible = false
                window.cTransponder_visible = true
                window.cTransponder_add001_visible = false
                window.bumper_visible = true
                window.bumper_add001_visible = false
                window.dangerousPoint_visible = true
                window.sieve_visible = true
                window.sieve_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_visible = true
                window.platform_add001_visible = false
                window.platform_add002_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_visible = true
                window.stoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.stoppingPoint_add002_visible = false
                window.pStoppingPoint_visible = true
                window.pStoppingPoint_add001_visible = false
                window.radioAntenna_visible = true
                window.radioAntenna_add001_visible = false
                window.radioCellLimit_visible = true
                window.radioCellLimit_add002_visible = false
                window.zcTerritory_visible = true
                window.zcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.cbtcTerritory_visible = true
                window.cbtcTerritory_add002_visible = false
                window.update_view = true //表示変化あり
                window.train_view = true //列車表示あり
                window.symbol_visible = true
            }else if(viewmode.currentIndex === 4){ //Line Detail4
                window.segment_visible = true
                window.segment_add001_visible = true
                window.segment_add002_visible = true
                window.tc_visible = true
                window.tc_add002_visible = true
                window.tc_add003_visible = true
                window.signal_visible = true
                window.signal_add001_visible = true
                window.sw_visible = true
                window.sw_add002_visible = true
                window.trainStop_visible = true
                window.trainStop_add001_visible = true
                window.virtualSignal_visible = true
                window.virtualSignal_add001_visible = true
                window.virtualBlock_visible = true
                window.virtualBlock_add001_visible = true
                window.awsTS_visible = true
                window.awsTS_add001_visible = true
                window.cbtcTS_visible = true
                window.cbtcTS_add001_visible = true
                window.rlTS_visible = true
                window.rlTS_add001_visible = true
                window.transponder_visible = true
                window.transponder_add001_visible = true
                window.cTransponder_visible = true
                window.cTransponder_add001_visible = true
                window.bumper_visible = true
                window.bumper_add001_visible = true
                window.dangerousPoint_visible = true
                window.sieve_visible = true
                window.sieve_add001_visible = true
                window.platform_visible = true
                window.platform_add001_visible = true
                window.platform_add002_visible = true
                window.stoppingPoint_visible = true
                window.stoppingPoint_add001_visible = true
                window.stoppingPoint_add002_visible = true
                window.pStoppingPoint_visible = true
                window.pStoppingPoint_add001_visible = true
                window.radioAntenna_visible = true
                window.radioAntenna_add001_visible = true
                window.radioCellLimit_visible = true
                window.radioCellLimit_add002_visible = true
                window.zcTerritory_visible = true
                window.zcTerritory_add002_visible = true
                window.cbtcTerritory_visible = true
                window.cbtcTerritory_add002_visible = true
                window.update_view = true //表示変化あり
                window.train_view = false //列車表示なし
                window.symbol_visible = true
            }else if(viewmode.currentIndex === 5){ //手動
                window.update_view = true //表示変化あり
                window.train_view = true //表示変化なし
            }
        }

    }
    //Mode文字列表示
    Text{
        id:mode_text
        font.pointSize: 12
        width: 60
        height: 35
        anchors.right:viewmode.left
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.top:viewmode.top
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        text:Text_Js.mode[Text_Js.language_no]
    }

    //コンボボックスとその他のボタンを仕切る
    ToolSeparator{
        id: separator2
        height: 40
        anchors.left:viewmode.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 5
        anchors.top:parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 2
    }
```